# Using WSO2Developer Studio version 3.8.0 How can write Custom Task Class

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using WSO2Developer Studio version 3.8.0. I am going to write Custom Task class following are the steps: 1. I have created the following class

```
package com.training.mediators;

import org.apache.synapse.ManagedLifecycle;
import org.apache.synapse.core.SynapseEnvironment;
import org.apache.synapse.startup.Task;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CronjobTask implements Task,ManagedLifecycle{  

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(SynapseEnvironment arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("CronjobTask init method****************");
    }

}


2. When i import the org.apache.synapse.startup.Task Developer studio shows that it is deprecated.
3. How can i implement the method  execute() of the Task interface.If it is deprecated.
```

Please guide me what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom task should implements org.apache.synapse.task.Task, not org.apache.synapse.startup.Task

Comment: when i try to import org.apache.synapse.task.Task. The developer studio gave me error import org.apache.synapse.task.Task can not be resolved.So how can i add this package

Comment: Thank you  Jean-Michel.I have added the jar problem is solved.